# Разные файлы настроек в ветках git

Tags: git

Вопрос по git
Есть две ветки master и develop
В каждой ветке свой файл настроек для сайта, на master для продакшена, develop для тестового сайта.
Как сделать так чтобы при merge файлы настроек сайта не передавались между ветками.

Comment: Обычно нежелательно хранить настройки в гите.

Comment: А как Вам идея не коммитить изменения, котрые сделны в develop? То есть они лежат локально, и никуда не передаются с машины разработчика

Comment: Кстати, если файлы не меняются, то и конфликтов в них нет.

Comment: @S.H., я думал, develop - это для CI.

Comment: @Qwertiy - да, тогда такой способ не подходит...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, рекомендуется не хранить файлы настроек в гите.

Во-вторых, что-то я сомневаюсь, что файлы настроек постоянно меняются. А если файлы не меняют, то и конфликтов между ними нет. По крайней мере, если они хоть раз были помёрджены.
Так что надо при ближайшем мёрдже просто выбрать нужную версию файла и всё. Ну или сделать мёрдж только с этим файлом с использованием `-s ours`.

Comment: Файлы настроек не меняются просто они разные.
В ветке master - для рабочего сервера
В ветке develop - для тестового.

Скорее всего правильнее будет просто удалить их из репозитария git и добавить в исключения.

Comment: Ну так я как раз для такого случая и ответил - когда настройки не меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Конфигурация тут привязана не к ветке, а к конкретной инсталляции системы или к конкретному окружению (ну там dev, QA, staging, prod). То есть, например, у вас можно тот же `master` развернуть на QA системе, или staging системе или на проде.

При этом в каждом случае нужна своя конфигурация, ведь каждая система использует свою БД и т.п.

Далее, что важно, версионность самого программного продукта и конфигураций разная. Что я имею ввиду. Версия продукта меняется, когда вносятся изменения в продукт, т.е. добавляется новый функционал или исправляются ошибки. И версия соотносится с комитом в системе контроля версий. Изменение, скажем, сервера БД (или пароля к БД), который используется на prod системе не должен влиять на версию продукта (а значит не должен порождать комиты в репозитории продукта).

Конфигурация же меняется по другим причинам: появилась новая staging система, переехали на другой сервер БД, сменили пароли в процедуре ротации паролей. Это происходит независимо от программного продукта.

Удобно хранить конфигурацию в системе контроля версий:

1. есть история
2. можно делать review через pull request-ы
3. есть версионность самой конфигурации

Выход такой, что конфигурацию удобно хранить в отдельном репозитории. При этом конфигурацию для отдельных систем (типа QA, staging, prod) хранить в отдельных файлах или папках, а не ветках git.

При развертывании приложения имя конфигурации (это может быть имя QA, staging, prod) является параметром. Т.е. процедура развертывания принимает на вход:

1. версию приложения
2. версию конфигурации
3. имя конфигурации

В простом случае версии могут неявно быть `master`, т.е. берем последнюю версию из `master` в обоих репозиториях.

И конечно все секреты (пароли, ключи) в репозитории с конфигурацией должны быть зашифрованы, а при развертывании нужно предоставить пароль/PGP-ключ для расшифровки.

Comment: Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь, что отдельный репозиторий решает больше проблем, чем создаёт. Никто не мешает держать папку с разными конфигами в основном репозитории. Да и ситуация с ветками и env'ами несколько притянута за уши.

Comment: Проекты разные. В простом случае можно и в одном репозитории. Для сложного проекта - это может быть оправдано.

Comment: @Qwertiy Про притянута за уши я не совсем понял. Вы не согласны с тезисом что `Конфигурация тут привязана не к ветке, а к конкретной инсталляции системы`?

Comment: Формально согласен, но обычно CI настроен на то, что конкретная ветка разворачивается на конкретный env и разворачивать на него же другую ветку требуется крайне редко.

Comment: Это то так. Но разные ветки/версии можно разворачивать на одном и том же env-e. Если конфигурация в ветке - то это уже не будет работать. Более того, обычно деплоим не ветку вообще, а тег. А они каждый раз разные. Так что, все равно выходит, что главное все же env, а не ветка.